# mongoose - Cast to number failed for value "[object Object]" at path

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Buyer',{
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String,
    url: String,
    id: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    credit: Number,
});
```

I am trying to add to their credit whenever they submit a Stripe payment, but when I do, I get the error that is in the title:

```
Cast to number failed for value "[object Object]" at path
```

Here is where I try to update `credit`:

```
    var query = Buyer.findOne({'_id': req.user._id});
    query.exec(function(err,buyer){
        buyer.credit = { credit: parseInt(req.body.amount,10) };
        buyer.markModified('credit');
        buyer.save(function (err) {
            if (!err) {
                //--NO ERROR
            } else {
              return console.log(err);
            }
        });
    });
```

I'm not sure how to add to existing credit, instead of overwriting it as I'm doing above, but I suppose I'll ask that in another question after looking further into it.

Anyways, I don't understand what is going on with my error. I tried doing it without the `parseInt` but noticed it was a string.

Comment: Have you debugged to determine what `req.body.amount` actually contains? I'm not familiar with some of these technologies but perhaps it's a `Number`, which can't be parsed using `parseInt`.

Comment: @Madbreaks It's a string. My very last sentence in the question mentioned that.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand your last sentence. What kind of string? If it's not a string representation of a number, what is it you're expecting `parseInt` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
buyer.credit = { credit: parseInt(req.body.amount,10) };
```

To:

```
buyer.credit = req.body.amount;
```

You just want to set `buyer.credit` to the value, not another object with its own `credit` field. You don't need to the `parseInt` because Mongoose will do that for you based on your definition of `credit` as a `Number` in the schema.

You can also remove the `buyer.markModified('credit');` line.